# Duda de RecyclerView en Firebase (Android/JAVA)

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este nodo llamado "*Orders*" en mi base de datos *Firebase*, este nodo almacena como nodos hijos, el ID único de cada "*Orden*", el ID, a su vez, posee mismo ID, el rut del usuario que solicitó la orden, el estado, y un nodo "orderItems", que almacena los productos solicitados en la orden.

Mi idea es capturar los datos de cada orden y reciclarlos con *RecyclerView* en un *Cardview*. Sin embargo, logro capturar los datos individuales (sin hijos), pero no sé cómo capturar el nodo hijo "*orderItems*", ¿se trabaja con *ArrayList* o cómo se podría hacer?

Adjunto el código del ViewHolder

```
public class RecievedOrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView txtRutUser,txtProdName,txtProdQuantity;

public RecievedOrderViewHolder (View itemView){
    super(itemView);
    txtRutUser = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRutCliente);
    txtProdName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
    txtProdQuantity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductQuantity);
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 }
}
```

Y el código de la Activity donde se carga el RecyclerView

```
public class RecievedOrdersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView recyclerViewOrders;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOrders;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOrdersProducts;

FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference tableOrders;



FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, RecievedOrderViewHolder> adapterOrders;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieved_orders);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    tableOrders = db.getReference("Orders");


    recyclerViewOrders = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
    recyclerViewOrders.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManagerOrders = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerViewOrders.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOrders);


    layoutManagerOrdersProducts = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    loadListOrder();






}

private void loadListOrder() {


    adapterOrders = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, RecievedOrderViewHolder>(Order.class,R.layout.order_item,RecievedOrderViewHolder.class,tableOrders) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(RecievedOrderViewHolder viewHolder, Order model, int position) {

            viewHolder.txtRutUser.setText(model.getRutUser());




        }
    };

    recyclerViewOrders.setAdapter(adapterOrders);



 }
}
```

Hasta el momento, solo seteo el rut del usuario, pero no sé como acceder a los valores del nodo orderItems, y capturar esos datos y luego setearlos. Porque tengo entendido que en el adapter como parámetro, se coloca la clase POJO que luego se usara para llamar a "*model.getAtributo()*". El drama esta en que "*orderItems*", contiene objetos de la clase POJO *Producto*, he ahí mi duda.

Comment: Hola victor, nos facilitarias el codigo que usaste para traerlos al Recycler ? de esa forma podemos ayudarte

Comment: Listo, Gastón, ahí adjunté el código